# Nifi ConsumeAMQP throwing NullPointerException

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-nifi, consumer

We use default ConsumeAMQP and Nifi version 1.18.0.

RabbitMQ connection is successful, when data comes from RabbitMQ, ConsumeAMQP processor is throwing NullPointerException.

Once exception occurs, there is increase in consumer at rabbitmq side. Probably it's because, it can not kill the consumer that throws the exception.

**How can we consume data without any exceptions? I have some suspicion about the exception stack trace ".convertMapToString" but how can fix it?**

[image]
[image]

**RabbitMQ Message:**

```
Exchange    EXCHANGE.EX
Routing Key ROUTING.TEST
Redelivered ●
Properties  
    app_id: UI.XXX|TEST|0|1
    user_id:    XYZUSER
    timestamp:  123456
    priority:   0
    delivery_mode:  2
headers:    
    ClassName:  Test.UI.X.Y
    FileName:   undefined
    LineNumber: 0
    MethodName: MethodName
    singularityheader:  notxdetect=True
    content_encoding:   utf8
    content_type:   text/plain
Payload 278 bytes
    Encoding: string
TestLog| Testlogcontent| Testlog value....
```

**Exception Log:**

```
    2022-11-30 13:22:56,818 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP ConsumeAMQP[id=b0520c61-32aa-386d-20ac-9a2a34c14a30] Processor failure
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP.convertMapToString(ConsumeAMQP.java:237)
        at org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP.buildHeaders(ConsumeAMQP.java:220)
        at org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP.buildAttributes(ConsumeAMQP.java:192)
        at org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP.processResource(ConsumeAMQP.java:172)
        at org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.ConsumeAMQP.processResource(ConsumeAMQP.java:47)
        at org.apache.nifi.amqp.processors.AbstractAMQPProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractAMQPProcessor.java:223)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1354)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2022-11-30 13:22:57,001 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.c.r.StandardProcessSession Failed to asynchronously commit session StandardProcessSession[id=323331374] for ConsumeAMQP[id=b0520c61-32aa-386d-20ac-9a2a34c14a30]
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=db0849b7-f695-4f7c-b5a7-6bffb6c33d8d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1669802459297-401, container=default, section=401], offset=33821, length=147],offset=0,name=db0849b7-f695-4f7c-b5a7-6bffb6c33d8d,size=147] transfer relationship not specified. This FlowFile was created in this session and was not transferred to any Relationship via ProcessSession.transfer()
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.validateCommitState(StandardProcessSession.java:259)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.checkpoint(StandardProcessSession.java:274)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:556)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commitAsync(StandardProcessSession.java:510)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:28)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1354)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].